# Unable to Delete code using backspace unless holding down SHIFT

Tags: android-studio

I can't simply delete code as I am typing unless I hold SHIFT along with backspace.

Delete works, but only delete after the spot.

Backspace works fine in other software and on the web.
No keyboard shortcuts are enabled

(Running Android Studio 3.4.1)

Answer (score 1):

try to do this :
go to `file > setting > search for (backspace)`

`Right-click on backspace > remove backspace_shift`

you will have this screen :

[image]

Comment: Is it useful answer?!
@andrew